# How to serve a finished Wordpress Website locally

Tags: wordpress, apache, azure-hub

I downloaded a website and its respective database from Microsoft Azure using FTP with Filezilla and I want to serve it locally. I already set the environment:

- MySQL
- Apache
- PHP
- phpMyAdmin
- Wordpress

What is the next step to deploy the website? Should I copy the website folder in `htdocs` directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used the plugin Duplicator of Wordpress. This plugin allows me to create a full copy of a remote Wordpress site and an installer file. Once you generate these files you just have to copy them in the web server directory (or in a subdirectory like "MyWebsite") and execute the installer with your web browser going to:

```
http://localhost:port/MyWebsite/installer.php
```

I hope this is useful to someone. Cheers!